# Android - checking if the device is connected to the internet

Tags: android

is there any simple way, how to check if the device is actively connected into internet (= is connected via GPRS, EDGE, UMTS, HSDPA or Wi-Fi)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I use isReachable.

```
public class Extras {
    public static class Internet {
        public static boolean isOnline() {
            try {
                InetAddress.getByName("google.ca").isReachable(3);
                return true;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e){
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i my case I am getting some informatin relating GPS, and when there is lost of GSM connection, I got bad bevahiour. I could only add it into while(1) loop and check continuously if the internet target is reachable, which could "eat" from my FUP data limit. I was wondering if there is some internal checking, like, is Internet connection accessible do something, if not don't do anything

Answer (score 3):

I use this in one of my apps:

```
private boolean isOnline()  {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (ni != null && ni.isConnected());
}
```

You will need these permissions in your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Does that return if there is a network connection or really if that network is connected to Internet?

Comment: ForceMagic mean if it return false if your device is connected to router without network connection, or if your device is connected to capative network or real network

Answer (score 1):

You can try retreaving the Local IP address to check whether device is connected to Internet.

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumeration = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); enumeration.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumeration.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddress.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress iNetAddress = enumIpAddress.nextElement();
            if (!iNetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                return iNetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

The return iNetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); will give you the IP address. You need to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Note: If you are working in Emulator it will retun the emulator IP (generally it will be 10.0.2.15)

Comment: If you are connected to a Wifi network this would still give you a local IP but your Wifi router may not be connected to the internet.