# How to check device is just connected to the Internet

Tags: android

Is there a way to check when a device, which has not been connected to the Internet , is just connected. If I connect the phone to the Internet inside my application, I should do some actions (e.g. `Toast`).

**Note:** It is not the same question with [Detect if Android device has Internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection)
 and [Android - checking if the device is connected to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764783/android-checking-if-the-device-is-connected-to-the-internet).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26114247/5502638 check this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

Comment: Can you justify how it is not the same as the questions you mentioned?